# What is the point of IEnumerator?

Tags: .net, for-loop, ienumerator

[This is an excellent video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd3yUjGc9M0) explaining what it is and the differences, but it seems it has a fundamental flaw, you can't skip around the list; it even lacks a Previous() method.

I was sending a list off to a function after if it found a match, instead of the original for...next starting from the next index, i just returned the row of where the next match was found in the function, as it has already done a secondary loop to read all the lines between each 'Hello' block.

I can't do any of this with an iteration class like IEnumerator; am i missing something?

```
For row As Integer = 0 To dataList.Count - 1
    If row <> -1 Then
       If dataList.Item(row) = "Hello" Then row = SayHello(row)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What's `dataList`? The ASP.NET control has no `Item` but an `Items` property. It's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: What makes you think this is dealing with ASP.NET? (Not that it's relevant, in any case)

Comment: @AdamRobinson: I've asked what type it is to understand the real problem behind this theoretical question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: He's asking about `IEnumerator`, not about the specific code in his question.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: If the code is not related at all it is unnecessary.  Something with a `Count` property and with an index is not a good example for an IEnumerator since it probably implements `IList` as the `for-loop` suggests.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: [datalist] is a list i populated from rows in an excel file using StreamReader; the original name was [rawData] but i changed it to [dataList] for the question to denote it was indeed a list.

Answer (score 2):

> you can't skip around the list

You say that's a flaw. It isn't when you don't want to allow skipping around a list.

The number one thing people do with lists is iterate over them - this is the lowest common denominator for collections of all types.

If you do need to skip around, as in your example, don't use `IEnumerator`.

Comment: I understand that IEnumerator is just a posh loop counter that remembers state, but without a Previous() method et al, then it's a futile approach that can be replicated with for...next or for...each. *Caveat: i'm a casual coder, so playing devil's advocate ;)

Comment: @Data: `IEnumerator` is the chief way that `foreach` is implemented. There are types that do not provide random access to the contained elements, such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet`. These can still, however, be enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the interface (and the accompanying `IEnumerable` interface) is to provide a forward-only mechanism for iterating over a collection (or similar structure). Given that, I don't think it's fair to say that it has a "fundamental flaw" because you cannot skip around or go in reverse any more than it would be fair to say that a compact car has a fundamental flaw because you can't use it to transport large farm animals.

Or, for those who may not favor car analogies, it's akin to saying a banana has a fundamental flaw because it (in an ordinary, unfrozen state) cannot be used to pound in nails.

Comment: You had to use a car analogy, eh ;)

Answer (score 0):

The very definition of enumerating is to mention things one by one. To enumerate is to start at the top and look at each item down the list. That is what enumerating is. So, something that is enumerable would be something that you could look at one by one from the top. The name IEnumerable is very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The point of an IEnumerator is to only serve ONE object at a time, which means you can save memory and/or time. To work with a list, you need to fill the list first. Even if you do not really need the complete list, but always use a single item at each iteration.

```
Private Iterator Function AllIntegers() As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Dim i = Integer.MinValue
    While i < Integer.MaxValue
        Yield i
    End While
End Function
```

Now you could do

```
For each i in AllIntegers
```

And now try to put all these integers into a List(Of Integer)